# OSError django after chmod

Tags: django

I have an upload system and this morning it was working right but when i came back this afternoon i get this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/media'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/blog/hojas/add/
Django Version:     1.6.1
Exception Type:     OSError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/media'

Exception Location:     /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py in makedirs, line 157
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.5
Python Path:    

['/home/yabir/Documentos/taqwim/proyecto',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol',
 '/home/my_username/projects']
```

after see it, I procced to give to my folder 755 permissions but it still not working.

Comment: What's the values of `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` in your `settings.py` file? and which process is running your code?

Comment: `755` would not be enough if the user who owns `media/media` is different from the user your webserver runs as. Please post your webserver's user and group, and the user and group owners of your `media/media` directory.